# How go compiler optimize the storage of string constants?

Tags: go

```golang
func TestStrRef(t *testing.T) {

    str1 := "hello"
    str2 := "hello"
    str3 := "hello"

    fmt.Println(str1, str2, str3)
}
```

Since the values of `str1 str2 str3` are the same and immutable, so it can store only one. Will go compiler optimize at this?

Comment: https://commaok.xyz/post/intern-strings/

Comment: The playground compiler implements the optimization.  https://play.golang.org/p/3Rr6cYwTbjo